# Java - How to make a form return a value?

Tags: java, swing, return-value, return-type

Bear in mind I'm a complete (2 weeks) java beginner, and might need things explained as if to a three year old.

I've created a form which is called by the main class.  It calls an arrayList of six objects from another class and displays the first four values on buttons.
The sixth item is a string 'qText' displayed on a text pane, while the fifth isn't displayed. So far so good.

pressing the a button should assign a value of 0, 1, 2, or 3 to variable 'qans'.

I would like to be able to check whether 'qans' has the same value as variable 'ans' and return either an int or bool to the main class.

```
package lp2;

import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 *
 * @author david
 */
public class form extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    ArrayList set = methods.getquestion();

        int a = (int) set.get(0);
        int b = (int) set.get(1);
        int c = (int) set.get(2);
        int d = (int) set.get(3);
        int ans = (int) set.get(4);

        int qans;

        int check = (int) set.get(qans);


        String qText = (String) set.get(5);

        String stringA = String.valueOf(a);
        String stringB = String.valueOf(b);
        String stringC = String.valueOf(c);
        String stringD = String.valueOf(d);
        String stringAns = String.valueOf(ans);




    /**
     * Creates new form form
     */
    public form() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        btnA = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnB = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnC = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btnD = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTextArea1.setEditable(false);
        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jTextArea1.setText(qText);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        btnA.setText(stringA);
        btnA.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnAActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnB.setText(stringB);
        btnB.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnBActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnC.setText(stringC);
        btnC.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnCActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnD.setText(stringD);
        btnD.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnDActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(btnA, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 350, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnB, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 350, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnC, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 350, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnD, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 350, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(28, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 90, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(btnA, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(btnB, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(btnC, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(btnD, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 54, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        




    private void btnAActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     



int qans =0;
    }                                    

    private void btnBActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
int qans = 1;        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                    

    private void btnCActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
int qans = 2;        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                    

    private void btnDActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
int qans = 3;        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                    





    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(form.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(form.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(form.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(form.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new form().setVisible(true);
            }
        });



    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnA;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnB;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnC;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnD;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    // End of variables declaration                   








}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please take the [tour], then go through the [help] and learn [ask] a question, and finally post a proper well formatted [mcve]

Comment: `"I would like to be able to check whether 'qans' has the same value as variable 'ans'"` - So.... `if (qans == ans)` ?

Comment: *"Bear in mind I'm a complete (2 weeks) java beginner, and might need .."* ..to go back to learning things on the command line, then when starting GUIs go through the tutorial. Don't expect us to spoon feed information to you, and if you need to open a question with a statement like that, it is a good sign you are in over your head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions:

1. If you want a window, one that does not represent the main application (here your "main class" whatever that is) to *return* a value, then don't use a JFrame which can never be used in a modal fashion but rather use a modal dialog such as via a modal JDialog.
2. For this and many other reasons, you should avoid have your GUI classes extend top-level windows such as JFrame (or JDialog for that matter). Instead have your GUI classes produce JPanes, and these can be placed into the top level window that is most appropriate for your need.
3. You're **shadowing** your qans variable, so that the field will never change, no matter what button is pushed, meaning you're **re-declaring** the variable within a method or constructor, and thus creating and setting the state (assigning a value to ) a local variable, and doing this will not change the state of the class instance field. The solution is not to **re-declare** the variable. So in the action performed methods, change `int qans = 1;` to `qans = 1;`, and likewise for all the other similar bits of code.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at both [`JFileChooser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) and [`JOptionPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html), which are both 'forms' ('windows' in java terminology) but return their value in different ways.

`JOptionPane` has a static method that shows the dialog, waits until it's done, and returns the result immediately.

`JFileChooser` works by creating an instance (like you do), making it visible (like you do), waits until its done, and after its done you can interrogate the object by invoking 'getter' methods (ask different types of results)

You can mimic either of these but the second is more powerful.

The waiting-until-done part is handled automatically for you if you use a `JDialog` instead of `JFrame`.

Some terminology to get you up to speed:

- Window - every separate GUI you can make
- Frame - a window with title bar, close button, etc
- Dialog - a frame which is 'modal'
- Modal - means it blocks execution of whatever made it visible, until it is made invisible
- getter - a method that returns a field: like `public int getQans() { return qans; }`
- field - a variable defined in the class (your `qans`, `set`, etc.)